# showDialog() - Attempting to trigger dialog modal based on error message retrieved from Firebase Authentication API call

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to establish error handling for my app.

Backend is Firebase.

Intended functionality:

- In the case the API call returns a response with an error message,
- make the determination of what the error message is and display the text that is appropriate for that error message and
- deploy a modal to display a particular error message according to the error response from the API call.

I believe that the HttpException logic established in the Auth class is not being passed over via the provider so instead the method `on HttpException catch (error)` is calling on HttpException and not the logic established within the Auth provider.

The code still runs bot only the terminal displays the error. Modal does not deploy.

Here is an example of an error API call I receive:

```
I/flutter (29822): {error: {code: 400, message: EMAIL_NOT_FOUND, errors: [{message: EMAIL_NOT_FOUND, domain: global, reason: invalid}]}}
```

I'm attempting to target the message within the error response

```
final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        //if the API call retrieves an error
        throw HttpException(
          //throw custom error handling method
          message: responseData['error']['message'],
          //display the error message returned in the API call (the value assigned to the message within the error array)
        );
      }
```

And then pass it through the Provider.

Provider that holds API calls:

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String _token;
  DateTime _tokenExpirationDate;
  String _userID;

  final String apiKey = #; //redacted

  //AUTHENTICATION method - extracted to reduce reuse of code
  Future<void> _authenticate(
      {String email, String password, String urlSegment}) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:$urlSegment?key=$apiKey');
    //.parse method allows the use of the full url
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode({
          'email': email,
          'password': password,
          'returnSecureToken': true,
        }),
      );
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        //if the API call retrieves an error
        throw HttpException(
          //throw custom error handling method
          message: responseData['error']['message'],
          //display the error message returned in the API call (the value assigned to the message within the error array)
        );
      }
      print(response.statusCode);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  //AUTHENTICATION CREATE API call - Register user
  Future<void> signup(String email, String password) async {
    _authenticate(
      email: email,
      password: password,
      urlSegment: 'signUp',
    );
  }

//AUTHENTICATION READ API call - user sign in
  Future<void> signin(String email, String password) async {
    _authenticate(
      email: email,
      password: password,
      urlSegment: 'signInWithPassword',
    );
  }
}
```

Standardized error handling class:

```
class HttpException implements Exception {
  HttpException({this.message});
  final String message;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return message;
  }
}
```

Authentication card that displays UI and interaction logic:

```
  //VOID function to display a dialog modal. We will use this to display a dialog modal and populate the message with whatever error message the API call returns
  void _errorDialog({String message}) {
    showDialog(
      //in the case that an error occurs, by us putting the return in front of showDialog, showDialog will fulfill that Future in case of the error. If there is no error the .then will fulfill the expected Future value
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('An error occurred'),
        content: Text(message),
        //we will change the value of message to display according to what the API call returns
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Okay'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //SUBMIT button logic
  Future<void> _submit() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      // Invalid!
      return;
    }
    //Invalid response from user
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    //ATTEMPT TO MAKE API CALLS BASED ON ENUM STATE OF DISPLAY
    try {
      if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
        //USER LOGIN
        //call the sign in (read) API
        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).signin(
          _authData['email'],
          _authData['password'],
        );
      } else {
        //REGISTER USER
        //call the register (create) API
        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).signup(
          _authData['email'],
          _authData['password'],
        );
      }
    } on HttpException catch (error) {
      //we are conducting a filter on the type of errors we want to handle within this block.
      //here we are calling on the HttpException
      var httpErrorMessage = 'Could not login or sign up.';
      //all of the following error messages were retrieved from the Firebase Auth API documentation
      if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_EXISTS')) {
        //if the API call retrieves a value of 'EMAIL_EXISTS' in the error message
        httpErrorMessage = 'This email is alreary in use';
        //display the above error message
      } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_EMAIL')) {
        //if the API call retrieves a value of 'INVALID_EMAIL' in the error message
        httpErrorMessage = 'This is not a valid email.';
        //display the above error message
      } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_EMAIL')) {
        //if the API call retrieves a value of 'INVALID_EMAIL' in the error message
        httpErrorMessage = 'This is not a valid email.';
        //display the above error message
      } else if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')) {
        //if the API call retrieves a value of 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND' in the error message
        httpErrorMessage = 'Could not find a user with that email.';
        //display the above error message
      } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_PASSWORD')) {
        //if the API call retrieves a value of 'INVALID_PASSWORD' in the error message
        httpErrorMessage = 'Invalid password.';
        //display the above error message
      }
      _errorDialog(message: httpErrorMessage);
      //call the error dialog method
      //display in the message whatever defined message to display according to the API error response
    } catch (error) {
      //calling on the error that was established in the Auth class catch(error) {throw error} method in the addProduct function
      const errorMessage =
          'Experiencing network difficulties. Please try again';
      _errorDialog(message: errorMessage);
      //call the error dialog method
      //display in the message whatever defined message to display according to the API error response
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not returning anything in the signIn, signUp future methods. I needed to return the _authenticate method:

```
//AUTHENTICATION CREATE API call - Register user
  Future<void> signup(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(
      email: email,
      password: password,
      urlSegment: 'signUp',
    );
  }

//AUTHENTICATION READ API call - user sign in
  Future<void> signin(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(
      email: email,
      password: password,
      urlSegment: 'signInWithPassword',
    );
  }
```